# Symbol versioning issue in Linux dynamic loader (ld.so)

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, symbols, ld

I'm overriding the *fsync* library call in my program using LD_PRELOAD, but the behavior is very different in two seemingly identical RH 6.10 machines.

Is there something in *ld.so* that controls symbol versioning matching? I've tried a variety of *LD_* options without success.

```
Machine 1:

\[root@source\]# readelf -s -d testprogram | grep fsync
250: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND fsync@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
656175: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND fsync@@GLIBC_2.2.5

\[root@source\]# readelf -s -d test.so | grep fsync
497: 0000000000038712   117 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 fsync

\[root@source\]# LD_PRELOAD=test.so ./testprogram --\> works

LD_DEBUG OUTPUT:
binding file testprogram \[0\] to test.so \[0\]: normal symbol \`fcntl' \[GLIBC_2.2.5\]
```

```
Machine 2:

Identical readelf output

BUT

\[root@source\]# LD_PRELOAD=test.so ./testprogram --\> does not work

LD_DEBUG OUTPUT:

symbol=fcntl;  lookup in file=/usr/lib64/libinject.so \[0\]
symbol=fcntl;  lookup in file=/lib64/libm.so.6 \[0\]
symbol=fcntl;  lookup in file=/lib64/libpthread.so.0 \[0\]
binding file testprogram \[0\] to /lib64/libpthread.so.0 \[0\]: normal symbol \`fcntl' \[GLIBC_2.2.5\]
```